# sample sequence table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, spring-jdbc

I have decided to use mysql sequence table, since I am using spring jdbc batch insert (can't get primary key with this feature), where I will be pass generated key while inserting each row, I have googled long time now, didnt get proper way of creating sequence table.

I have created a sequence table

```
create table table_sequence (value int not null) ENGINE = MYISAM;
```

but I feel it seems to be very basic, since I need to have max value, and cache limit for each instance.

I have many tables, do I need to have one sequence table for each table?

I have very less idea about db sequence, so suggestion are helpful to me. thanks

Answer (score 0):

this may help you:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

```
CREATE TABLE animals (
     id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;

INSERT INTO animals (name) VALUES
    ('dog'),('cat'),('penguin'),
    ('lax'),('whale'),('ostrich');

SELECT * FROM animals;
```